# Android android.permission.SEND_SMS not working

Tags: java, android, sms

I'm trying to send a SMS from my emulator to the second emulator

The main problem is that Android android.permission.SEND_SMS is not working probably.

I'm not sure is the problem because I have the latest SDK installed or what ?

I get the following expectation error that I don't have android.permission.SEND_SMS.

```
12-02 21:46:04.150 7881-7881/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.alakeel.sms-2/lib/x86_64
12-02 21:46:04.240 7881-7881/com.example.alakeel.sms D/---: Fail
12-02 21:46:04.240 7881-7881/com.example.alakeel.sms W/System.err: java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: uid 10057 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS.
12-02 21:46:04.240 7881-7881/com.example.alakeel.sms W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
12-02 21:46:04.240 7881-7881/com.example.alakeel.sms W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
12-02 21:46:04.240 7881-7881/com.example.alakeel.sms W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendTextForSubscriber(ISms.java:768)
12-02 21:46:04.240 7881-7881/com.example.alakeel.sms W/System.err:     at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessageInternal(SmsManager.java:310)
12-02 21:46:04.240 7881-7881/com.example.alakeel.sms W/System.err:     at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:293)
12-02 21:46:04.240 7881-7881/com.example.alakeel.sms W/System.err:     at com.example.alakeel.sms.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
12-02 21:46:04.240 7881-7881/com.example.alakeel.sms W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
12-02 21:46:04.240 7881-7881/com.example.alakeel.sms W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
12-02 21:46:04.240 7881-7881/com.example.alakeel.sms W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
12-02 21:46:04.240 7881-7881/com.example.alakeel.sms W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
12-02 21:46:04.240 7881-7881/com.example.alakeel.sms W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
12-02 21:46:04.240 7881-7881/com.example.alakeel.sms W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
12-02 21:46:04.240 7881-7881/com.example.alakeel.sms W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-02 21:46:04.240 7881-7881/com.example.alakeel.sms W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
12-02 21:46:04.240 7881-7881/com.example.alakeel.sms W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
12-02 21:46:04.240 7881-7881/com.example.alakeel.sms W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-02 21:46:04.240 7881-7881/com.example.alakeel.sms W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
12-02 21:46:04.240 7881-7881/com.example.alakeel.sms W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Code for Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.alakeel.sms">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Code for MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage("+5554", null, "Bus will be at your door in 30 seconds", null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("---", "Sent");

        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("---","Fail");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @MikeM. fixed my problem thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Since I'm using API 23 , I fixed it just by adding the request permission to my activity

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},1);
```

Comment: This Work for me still in 2020